# Task Manager is showing that ,specifically video games, are using too much power

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, power, gaming, amd-ryzen

[image: Pic of Task Manager]

[image: System Specs]

- GPU: ASrock Challenger RX 5600 XT,
- PSU: Thermaltake Smart series 600 W.

I recently bought a pre-built budget gaming PC. For some reason, and only when playing High-CPU taking games (CSGO and Siege), my computer would blue-screen, completely restart, occasionally shut down, and overlay the desktop randomly while not being able to play. Randomly enough VR, Oculus RS, runs perfectly. At first, upon researching, I believed the problem to be CPU overheat. It was not (I tested). Now I believe that the PSU is the problem. How could I test for that?

To check for over-heating, I used both PC internal and external thermometers. Temperature stays at 25°C unless I am playing a game, then it goes up to 30-35°C. I figured any over-heating would stop when I added an external fan along side a simple (no flush) water cooling to my CPU. Using OCCT to stress test my PC shows the trip limit for my CPU being 115°C. This test (ran for 30 min) indicates that my temp doesn't exceed 60°C, and base temp is 30-32°C.

I ran through with WindBG to look at my mini dumps:

[minidump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSOvL.png) | [minidump pt.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfCrR.png) | [pt. 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Fr1T.png)

These pics were from the random mini dumps that Windbg offered to debug initially. I went through some more and found something about my display driver.
[Display driver problem?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Zsmw.png) (VIDEO_TDR_FAILURE (116))

I am making sure to keep updated on drivers, through windows check system + Radeon software. Any help?

From the minidumps that I looked at, the error I got told me that it was either a cpu overload (which I already ruled out), power supply, or memory issues.

- Since the complete factory reset, blue screens and computer restarts have stopped, but the screen would continue to hang. Although it now takes longer for this to happen, it has now started to occur with external video sources (youtube, funimation). So now I am thinking it's something faulty with my graphics card. Any info?

Comment: The graphics card brand doesn't tell us anything, we need the model.

Comment: Counter-Strike is a very CPU-intensive game. Can you provide the specs of your PC? Even better if you can provide a crash dump alongside the specs.

Comment: Please provide the exact make and model of all major PC components. How did you check for overheating? What were the exact results?

Comment: By ` PC internal thermometers`, I assume you mean the built-in sensors? Did you test it with some kind of stress tool (such as, but by far not limited to, OCCT) that also shows temperatures from said sensors?